# Change UINavigationBar Back Button Image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am trying to change image of a button in the UIBarButtonItem. But i couldn't change it. It still shows the old image.

```
func showLogo(type:LogoType)
    {
            var logoName = "logo.png"
            var hightlightedLogoName = "logo_highlight.png"

            if (type == .Book){
                logoName = "logo_book.png"
                hightlightedLogoName = "logo_highlight_book.png"
            }

            let logoImage = UIImage(named: logoName)?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

            var logo_button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
            logo_button.setBackgroundImage(logoImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            logo_button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:hightlightedLogoName), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
            logo_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, logoImage!.size.width, logoImage!.size.height)
            logo_button.addTarget(self, action: "logoPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            var logoButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logo_button)
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoButton

    }
```

function call

```
self.showLogo(.Other) //Shows Default Logo
```

when i push to another screen. I am calling the same function

```
self.showLogo(.Book) //Shows Default Logo. Should Display Book Logo
```

Is there anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Where are you calling `self.showLogo()`? I don't see anything wrong with the function itself. I think the problem is when you call it during the sequence to push a view controller.

Comment: I have created a Abstract View Controller which is a base class for all view controllers. When i push a viewcontroller. It (self.showLogo()) will get called.

Comment: You might have the wrong parameter being called because of superclassing. Show us the relevant code.